# How to concatenate the lists within a tensor to a single list?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensor

suppose that I have the following tensor:

```
>> outputs
tensor([[-0.1260,  0.0463, -0.3362,  ...,  0.1089, -0.2454,  0.0140],
        [ 0.5050, -0.0750, -0.1639,  ..., -0.0020, -0.0521, -0.3224],
        [-0.5311,  0.4526,  0.0079,  ..., -0.0654, -0.1255, -0.0012],
        [ 0.0728, -0.1219,  0.0905,  ...,  0.1354,  0.2730, -0.1186],
        [-0.0680, -0.5570,  0.0295,  ..., -0.2411, -0.1690,  0.0331]],
       grad_fn=<SliceBackward>)
>> outputs.shape
Out[20]: torch.Size([5, 1024])
```

How can I concatenate the 5 lists that are contained in the tensor `outputs` and make it into a single list?

Thank you,

Comment: is `result = outputs.view(-1)` what you're looking for?

Comment: @HDB You should use `outputs.flatten()`, makes the code more explicit and easier to follow.

Comment: @Szymon Maszke yes I agree as long as you're using pytorch 0.4.1 or newer (which for new projects I hope you're using the lastest!)

Comment: Indeed, just giving some more context about best practices which @HDB might find useful now (and later on).